# How to let unix grep command to abort if pattern match fails

Tags: unix, grep

I have multiple unix commands in a script. A "cat file.txt | grep pattern" will proceed to next command sequentially if it matches. Else on no match the command should abort. Any single line commands to achieve this will help.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bash or sh, you can set the option `errexit` like so: `set -o errexit`

If you do that, then this line (and any other line) will abort your script if it fails:

```
grep pattern file.txt
```

Alternatively, you can simply use an `||` like this:

```
grep pattern file.txt || exit 1
```

Or, more verbosely, use an `if`:

```
if ! grep pattern file.txt; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

put your grep command in if else loop, if string does not matches use exit 0 command.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | grep pattern
```

can be written as

```
grep pattern file.txt
```

You can skip the next line on failure with `&&`

```
grep pattern file.txt && 
   echo "I am the next line"
```

or exit with

```
grep pattern file.txt || { echo "Grep found nothing"; exit 1; }
```